# Android configuration specific to each combination of 2 flavor dimensions

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle, android-productflavors

I am trying to add a second flavor dimension to an existing Android project. I already had a dimension for different environments (DEV, BETA, PROD), each with their own backend API and their own application id (to be able to install apps connected to several environments on the same device). And now I want to add another dimension for 2 variants of my app, a general one with all the features, and a specific one with a subset of features. And in addition to that, I still have the default debug and release build types I want to keep.

So here is what my configuration in build.gradle looks like so far:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 56
        versionName "1.1.6"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        manifestPlaceholders = [
                appAuthRedirectScheme: 'com.example'
        ]
    }
    signingConfigs {...}
    buildTypes {
        debug {...}
        release {...}
    }
    flavorDimensions "env", "variant"
    productFlavors {
        dev {
            dimension "env"
            applicationIdSuffix ".dev"
            resValue 'string', 'backend_url', 'https://dev.example.com/api/v1/'
            manifestPlaceholders = [
                    appAuthRedirectScheme: 'com.example.dev'
            ]
        }
        beta {
            dimension "env"
            applicationIdSuffix ".beta"
            resValue 'string', 'backend_url', 'https://beta.example.com/api/v1/'
            manifestPlaceholders = [
                    appAuthRedirectScheme: 'com.example.beta'
            ]
        }
        prod {
            dimension "env"
            resValue 'string', 'backend_url', 'https://example.com/api/v1/'
            manifestPlaceholders = [
                    appAuthRedirectScheme: 'com.example'
            ]
        }
        general {
            dimension "variant"
            applicationId "com.example"
        }
        specific {
            dimension "variant"
            applicationId "com.example.specific"
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

As you can see, I will be able to have an application variant specific to each environment/variant flavor by combining applicationId and applicationIdSuffix.

But I also need to have the corresponding mapping in manifestPlaceholders, knowing that the appAuthRedirectScheme placeholder is not integrated inside of my project's manifest, but in the [openId Appauth](https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-Android) dependency, so I can't just have several manifests in the various flavor directories like I have read elsewhere.

Is there a way to define a build setting in build.gradle that is specific to each flavor dimension combination? In other words, I would like to have different values of manifestPlaceholders for devGeneral, devSpecific, betaGeneral, betaSpecific, prodGeneral and prodSpecific.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand what you are trying to achieve. Do you want appAuthRedirectScheme to reflect the final applicationId of your app? In that case you can just use the ${applicationId} predefined placeholder in your manifest file. If you want very specific values for each combination of dimensions, then instead of 2 dimensions you should probably define a single dimension with 6 sets of values.

Comment: @BladeCoder I want appAuthRedirectScheme to be specific to each env/variant combination. And by convention it corresponds to the applicationId but it would be any other specific value. Using the ${applicationId} placeholder is not easy because the manifest elements that need to be customized come from a library, so I would have to play with manifest merging rules and so on and that feels brittle. I guess the one dimension with 6 flavors technique is the easiest even if that means a little bit of replication. I was just hoping that Gradle would allow me to set flavor specific config

Answer (score 2):

I don't specially advice this solution, but you could try the following approach:

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    if(variant.productFlavors.get(0).name == "dev") {
        if (variant.buildType.name == "debug" ) {
            variant.getMergedFlavor().manifestPlaceholders = [
                    appAuthRedirectScheme: 'com.example.dev'
            ]
        }
        if (variant.buildType.name == "release" ) {
            variant.getMergedFlavor().manifestPlaceholders = [
                    appAuthRedirectScheme: 'com.example.dev.foo'
            ]
        }
    }
    if(variant.productFlavors.get(0).name == "beta") { ... }
    if(variant.productFlavors.get(0).name == "prod") { ... }
}
```